# NextJS proxy file upload to an external node server

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, multer

I'm using NextJS and an external Node/Express Server to handle file uploads.

Everything is working if I upload directly from the browser to my external server but I want to proxy the upload from next to the external server.

Here's what i've tried (contract is the name of the field that holds the file:

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { companyId, investmentId } = req.query
  const queryString = req.url.split('?').pop()
  const { user } = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)

  const investment = await Investment.findOne({ _id: investmentId, company: companyId })
  if (!investment || investment.owner !== user._id) {
    return res.status(403).send('forbidden')
  }

  const url = 'http://localhost:3001/upload/contract?' + queryString
  // const url = 'https://contracts.citrus.fund/upload?' + queryString
  console.log(url)
  const response = await axios.post(url, {
    contract: req.body,
  })

  console.log(response.data)

  res.send({ ok: true })
}
```

The request arrives at my external server but multer doesn't handle it like a file:

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: async (req, file, cb) => {
    const directory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'documents', req.query.companyId)
    console.log({ directory })
    await mkdirp(directory)
    cb(null, directory)
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileName = 'c-' + req.query.investmentId + '.pdf'
    console.log({ fileName })
    cb(null, fileName)
  },
})

const uploader = multer({ storage })

router.post('/contract', uploader.single('contract'), (req, res) => {
  const { companyId, investmentId } = req.query
  res.send({ url: `/documents/${companyId}/c-${investmentId}.pdf` })
})
```

What do I have to do in my NextJS handler so my file arrives at the external server correctly?

Comment: You must set the header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` in `axios.post`, otherwise `multer` ignores the request. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#user-content--automatic-serialization

Comment: that makes sense. Now i'm getting "Field to long" from the external server, even though if i send directly from the browser, the same file, all goes well

Comment: You don't send any file with that `axios.post` request, you send a name/value pair `"contract": <string value of req.body>`. Your multipart payload looks different, for example, there is no `Content-Disposition: ... filename=...`.

Answer (score 0):

So this wasn't easy, but i finally made it work.
Here's my NextJs handler file:

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect'
import formidable from 'formidable'
import FormData from 'form-data'
import axios from 'axios'
import fs from 'fs'
import Company from 'rest/companies/companies.model'
import Investment from 'rest/investments/investments.model'
import { unstable_getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next'
import { authOptions } from 'pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]'

const { CONTRACTS_URL } = process.env

const form = formidable({ multiples: true })

const parseMultipartForm = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('in middleWare', req.headers['content-type'])
  const contentType = req.headers['content-type']

  if (contentType && contentType.indexOf('multipart/form-data') !== -1) {
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (!err) {
        req.body = fields // sets the body field in the request object
        req.files = files // sets the files field in the request object
      }
      next() // continues to the next middleware or to the route
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

const handler = nextConnect()
handler.use(parseMultipartForm)

handler.post(async function handler(req, res) {
  const { companyId, investmentId } = req.query
  const queryString = req.url.split('?').pop()
  const { user } = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)

  const investment = await Investment.findOne({ _id: investmentId, company: companyId })
  if (!investment || investment.owner !== user._id) {
    return res.status(403).send('forbidden')
  }

  const url = `${CONTRACTS_URL}/upload/contract?${queryString}`

  try {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('contract', fs.createReadStream(req.files.contract.filepath))
    console.log(1, formData)
    const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    })
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message)
  }

  res.send({ ok: true })
})

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
}

export default handler
```